# Why aren't any values loading into my Form Group?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to get a grasp on reactive forms using the Angular 2 documentation here
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html.  The way I'm trying to set up my form is a little different from how they're doing it in the tutorial but the same theory still applies.  Somewhere along the line I'm getting something mixed up because the variable that stores the imported data is `console.log()`ing perfectly fine, the `form group` is also logging perfectly fine, just with empty values.  Here's my code so far.

Question Model

```
export class Answers {
    id      = '';
    name    = '';
}

export class QuestionModel {
    question    = '';
    id          = '';
    name        = '';
    answers     : Answers[];
}



export const Question : QuestionModel[] = [
    {
    question: 'How do you feel about your current image?',
    id      : 'img-q1',
    name    : 'img-ques1',
    answers : [
        {
            id      : 'exp0101q',
            answer  : 'Its fine as is.'
        },
        {
            id      : 'exp0102q',
            answer  : 'I want to make minor adjustments.'
        },
        {
            id      : 'exp0103q',
            answer  : 'I want to change my image.'
        },
        {
            id      : 'exp0104q',
            answer  : 'Ive never wanted to use a particular image until now.'
        }
        ]
    }
]
```

Question Service

```
import { Injectable }               from '@angular/core';
import { Observable }               from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of }                       from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
import { QuestionModel, Answers,
         Question }                 from './question-model';



@Injectable()

export class QuestionService {

    getQuestions(): Observable<QuestionModel>{
        return of (Question);
    }
}
```

Question Component

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges,
         OnInit }                       from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup,
         FormBuilder, FormArray,
         Validators }                   from '@angular/forms';

import { QuestionModel, Answers }       from './question-model';

import { QuestionService }              from './question.service';



@Component({
    moduleId    : module.id,
    selector    : 'question-component',
    //template  : `<h1>question component</h1>`,
    templateUrl : 'question.component.html',
    providers   : [ QuestionService ]
})

export class QuestionComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    question: QuestionModel;
    quesForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private qservice : QuestionService, private fbuild : FormBuilder) {
        this.createForm();
    }

    createForm() {
        this.quesForm = this.fbuild.group({
            question: '',
            id      : '',
            name    : '',
            answers : this.fbuild.array([])
        });
    }

    ngOnChanges(){
        this.quesForm.setValue({
            question: this.question.question,
            id      : this.question.id,
            name    : this.question.name
        });

        this.setAnswers(this.question.answers);
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.qservice.getQuestions().subscribe(Question => {
            this.question = Question;
        });

        console.log(this.question);
        console.log(this.quesForm);
    }

    get answers(): FormArray {
        return this.quesForm.get('answers') as FormArray;
    };

    setAnswers(answers : Answers[]){
        const answersFGs = answers.map(answers => this.fbuild.group(answers));
        const answersFormArray= this.fbuild.array(answersFGs);
        this.quesForm.setControl('answers', answersFormArray)
    }


}
```

The Template

```
<h1>Question Component</h1>

<form [formGroup]="quesForm" novalidate>
    <fieldset [attr.id]="quesForm.value.id">

        <label>{{quesForm.value.question}}</label>

        <!--<div formGroupName="answers">
                <div *ngFor="let ans of answers">
                    <input type="radio" formControlName="name" 
                    [attr.id]="ans.id"
                    [attr.value]="ans.answer"
                    />
                <label>{{ans.answer}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>-->

    </fieldset>




    <!--<input type="text" formControlName="name" />
    <label>{{quesForm | json}}</label>-->

</form>

<p>{{quesForm.value | json}}</p>
<p>{{quesForm.status | json}}</p>
<p>{{question | json}}</p>
```

The only thing I tried was moving this

```
this.quesForm.setValue({
    question: this.question.question,
    id      : this.question.id,
    name    : this.question.name
});

this.setAnswers(this.question.answers);
```

into the `ngOnInit` but as I expected, I got an error saying there needs the be a value assigned to `question`, which is because it attempted to define it before the data was actually there.  I moved it back into the `ngOnChanges` and it goes back to coming up empty.

Inside the tutorial they set up a `submit` button and function as well as a `reset` function to update the input, but as far as I'm able to understand those don't have anything in them that sets the data.  From the looks of it I thought the code inside the `ngOnChanges` was what sets the values.  Am I right?  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to populate your form from data, I would remove the build of the form from constructor, and build the form when the data has been retrieved.

This way we can make sure we have values to build the form. So you can skip building the empty form (if you do not need it) and just build the form with your incoming values. So the `OnChanges` can be removed as well.

So build your form after data has been retrieved:

```
    this.qservice.getQuestions().subscribe(Question => {
        this.question = Question;
        this.createForm(); // do this!
    });
```

And your `createForm` function:

```
createForm() {
    this.quesForm = this.fbuild.group({
        question: this.question.question,
        id      : this.question.id,
        // ..... the rest 
    });
}
```

Comment: I just tried that a little bit ago I got an error saying it couldn't load question of "undefined".  I tried the elvis operator making it `this.question?.question` and I got another error saying it expected `:` right where the question mark was.

Comment: ok yeah I'm still getting a `cannot read property question of undefined` error.

Comment: Besides that how would I load the array of questions this way?

Comment: ok I just deleted the `createForm` from the `constructor` and now instead of just empty values it actually says `null`.  Though when I add the question part to it I start getting an `undefined` error on it.

Comment: In your example you are building a form based on an Object, but in your service you have an Array with an Object. Therefore the error I would say. I simplified your example, seems to work when I changed the Array with Object to just an object. https://plnkr.co/edit/nmBqs8MQ2vPaIq80BFsi?p=preview  But your form probably have several questions, so you would have to make some iteration and a Formarray of your questions as well.

Comment: If I were you. I would probably make this a template driven form, because I guess only validation you need is on the answers. It would be easier ;)

Comment: I was just coming here to tell you I figured out the same thing lol. it works perfectly now THANKS!!!.  please add that bit about the array to the answer for others.

Comment: actually I'm gonig to be adding functionality to it, which is the next hurdle to figure out.  I was told to make a reactive form for that.  When someone selects an answer it will toggle other components on and of depending on what they select.  Besides that I'll be using this component elsewhere in the site too.

Comment: Yeah, then you go with reactive form. Not knowing the whole app it's hard to suggest what's the best approach :) And you are welcome, glad I could help! :)